# Apply a function to a list of csv files

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, sapply

I have 45 csv files in a folder called myFolder. Each csv file has 13 columns and 640 rows.

I want to read each csv and divide the columns 7:12 by 10 and save it in a new folder called 'my folder'. Here's my appraoch which
is using the simple for loop.

```
library(data.table)
dir.create('newFolder')

allFiles <- list.files(file.path('myFolder'), pattern = '.csv')

for(a in seq_along(allFiles)){

    fileRef <- allFiles[a]
    temp <- fread(file.path('myFolder', fileRef)
    temp[, 7:12] <- temp[, 7:12]/10
    fwrite(temp, file.path('myFolder', paste0('new_',fileRef)))
 }
```

Is there a more simple solution in a line or two using datatable and apply function to achieve this?

Comment: You might be able to replace the `for` loop with an `apply` function, but the apply's anonymous function would look almost the same as your current for loop body.

Comment: What's your goal? Just to reduce the amount of code you typed? You're not really doing unnecessary steps, and "divide certain columns by 10 and save as a new file" isn't a common enough procedure to have a function that does it for you.

Comment: Yes. I want to reduce the amount of code and just in case, I have some very big csv files that lot of time to read in, maybe a more efficient code would be useful?

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with your code and you seek compactness, elegance, or refactoring, please ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). And as we try to convey against the unfortunate R myth: there is nothing wrong with `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is already pretty good but these improvements could be made:

- define the input and output folders up front for modularity
- use `full.names = TRUE` so that `allFiles` contains complete paths
- use `.csv$` as the pattern to anchor it to the end of the filename
- iterate over the full names rather than an index
- use `basename` in `fwrite` to extract out the base name from the path name

The code is then

```
library(data.table)

myFolder <- "myFolder"
newFolder <- "newFolder"

dir.create(newFolder)
allFiles <- list.files(myFolder, pattern = '.csv$', full.names = TRUE)

for(f in allFiles) {
    temp <- fread(f)
    temp[, 7:12] <- temp[, 7:12] / 10
    fwrite(temp, file.path(newFolder, paste0('new_', basename(f))))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr::walk` if you want to improve readability of your code and get rid of the loop:

```
allFiles <- list.files(file.path('myFolder'), pattern = '.csv')

purrr::walk(allFiles, function(x){
  temp <- fread(file.path('myFolder', x)
  temp[, 7:12] <- temp[, 7:12]/10
  fwrite(temp, file.path('myFolder', paste0('new_',fileRef)))
})
```

From the reference page of `purrr::walk`:

> walk() returns the input .x (invisibly)

I don't think it helps speed-wise, though.